# ¿Cómo puedo redireccionar a un usuario siendo admin o usuario normal a una Scena distinta?

Tags: mysql, javafx

Estoy tratando de redireccionar con bases de datos a una escena u otra 
un usuario determinado. Por ejemplo si es Administrador a su Scene, y si es Usuario a su departamento asignado.

El tema está en que no se aplicar la sentencia correcta para que redireccione ese nodo, ¿cómo debería de hacerlo?, Gracias de antemano !

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí si es usuario normal redirige a la pantalla de usuario, pero el tema está en que cuando el usuario esta asignado a un departamento por ejemplo admin, no lo envía, siempre va a la misma Scene...

```
@FXML
private void handledActionAcceder(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    try {

        String usuario = JF_tf_usuario.getText();
        String password = JF_tf_password.getText();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre =? and password =?";

        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, usuario);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        if (!resultSet.next()) {
            lbl_validacion.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:#B92D1D");
            lbl_validacion.setText("Ingrese el usuario y/o contraseña correctos");
        } else {
            Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
            Stage stage1 = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
            stage1.close();
            Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Departamento_de_usuarios/Empleados.fxml")));
            stage1.setTitle("Registro");
            stage1.setScene(scene);
            stage1.show();
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        lbl_validacion.setTextFill(Color.TOMATO);
        lbl_validacion.setText("Error al acceder a la tabla" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacerlo con FXMLLoader(). Si el usuario es adminsitrador cargas un panel y si no cargas otro panel.